# Doesn't Skype Support Grouping Contacts?

Tags: skype

The only groups Skype seems to support is starting a group conversation. Can't I pre-define groups like in MSN, etc? It's getting hard to find people all in a big list, I want to separate personal and work contacts and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using version `2.8.0.722` and I can easily create any group I want by right-clicking in the middle of the contact list and selecting `Add to Group > Create New Group`.